# How to get good quality of facebook profile picture?

Tags: windows, facebook-graph-api, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, facebook-fql

I am try to fetch profile picture from facebook to my windows store app but the quality of picture is too bad. 
Here is my code:

```
public void SetFriendsButtonImageSources(List<object> Result)
        {
            FriendsButtonImageIDs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            if (Result.Count > 0)
            {
                List<Image> images = new List<Image>() { FriendButtonImage1, FriendButtonImage2, FriendButtonImage3, FriendButtonImage4, FriendButtonImage5, FriendButtonImage6 };

                for (int i = 0; i < Result.Count; i++)
                {
                    var r = (IDictionary<string, object>)Result[i];
                    images[i].IsTapEnabled = true;
                    images[i].Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(r.ContainsKey("normal") ? (string)r["pic_square"] : "", UriKind.Absolute));
                    images[i].Tapped += HomePage_Tapped;
                    FriendsButtonImageIDs.Add("FriendButtonImage" + (i + 1),  r["uid"].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Please help me. How can i get good quality picture?

Comment: Where are you calling this method? Where is the *FQL* query?

Comment: Yes i was calling this method. But the problem is solved now. I did it using FQL.

Comment: You should answer your own question with what you did. This will help other SO users who have the same problem, and will mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by Facebook Query Language (FQL) and I m very late to answer this question since FQL is no longer available But still i think i should let people know how I solved it. As you can see in the  code that im querying for picture by keyword `pic_square` which is smaller in size hence lower quality.

So I used following query and it worked for me:

`SELECT src_big FROM photo WHERE pid IN 
   (SELECT cover_pid FROM album WHERE owner = $user_id AND name = 'Profile Pictures')`

For more information click this [link](http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/FQL:photo).